# Mongoose, array of references, right or wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When I was going through my node mongoose schema code I saw that I had written arrays of references in two different ways.

In some parts of the code I had written that managers is an array of user references

```
managers: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'user'
}]
```

But in other parts, I say that managers is a reference to user where the type is an array of objectIds

```
managers: {
  type: [mongoose.Schema.ObjectId],
  ref: 'user'
}
```

Both ways seems to work but does anyone know if there is any difference? Is one way an incorrect way of doing it?

### Edit:

I found a something that differs between the two.
When I query for the model and want to populate the managers the second version does not return the actual users.
The first one populates the managers and returns an array of user objects
but the second one returns an empty array, even though the array of managers contains ObjectIds of users...

### Edit 2:

Could it be that the first example should be used when referencing a schema in a separate comllection. If you look att all the examples in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html they are doing like in my first example.
The second one looks like it is being used when using a subschema inside the same collection.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: confirmed [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6102) that the second method should be used (go to the bottom of the thread).

Since it does not matter in your use case, I would suggest you use the form suggested in the thread linked above as it can matter in cases like the one that issue references.

---

The mongoose docs seem to use the second method. It also makes more sense to me logically, as I read it as the type is an array of objects. I do not believe they officially suggest one or another.

Check [this page](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) for some examples.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not really convinced...
The examples on the pages you are linking to is not showing an array of objectId references.
...and, as I added in the question I later found a difference when using populate. Then the first example seems to work better. Or have i missed something?